# Python 3.5.1 : NameError: name 'json' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import json as simplejson


    #write tweet objects to JSON
    file = open('tweet.json', 'wb') 
    print ("Writing tweet objects to JSON please wait...")
    for status in alltweets:
        json.dump(status._json,file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)

    #close the file
    print ("Done")
    file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    get_all_tweets("@AlertZaAfrica")
```

The python compiler says line 54 is wrong. I already defined import json as simplejson. The above area where I defined import json is showed above.

Comment: Show please where you define it.

Comment: That'd be why then... did you mean to do `import simplejson as json`? Why not just `import json` if you're using Python 3.5 anyway?

Comment: Ok, let me share the full code

Comment: `import simplejson as json`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should at first install simplejson to your system to be able to import it:

```
$ sudo pip3 install simplejson
```

Then in your code you are now able to import it:

```
import simplejson as json
```

From now on you will be able to access simplejson package using `json`.

Please note, if you're still using python 2 - despite this is not the OPs original question - you should do a

```
$ sudo pip install simplejson
```

instead.

Comment: I installed it, but still my python is not finding it.

Comment: @ScottyBlades I guess, your system python is not version 3. Since the question here is about python3, you might should do a simple pip install simplejson instead, so your system python, which is probably version 2, installs thje simplejson package. HTH